# Side bar pop out on click give strange results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple pop out menu that expands on click, then on click of the close icon close.

on click `left:250px`

on close `left:0`

This opens fine and closes fine, until I try and open again once I close then it will not open.

How can I fix this behavior and get it opening and closing normal.

```js
function openNav() {
  // event && event.stopPropagation();

  // document.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(mySidenav)[0], null).getPropertyValue("popoutwidth");
  // document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add('popoutwidthopen');
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "1";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.marginRight = "0";
}

function closeNav() {

  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add('popoutwidthclose');
  // document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "28";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.marginRight = "15";

}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* margin-top: 18px; */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffffba;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.popoutwidthopen {
  width: 250px
}

.popoutwidthclose {
  width: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-11" style=" margin-top: 7px;">
    <span id="hamburger-icon" onclick="openNav()" style="vertical-align: middle; opacity: 1; font-size: 28px; margin-right: 15px;">☰</span>
    <img class=" logo-img-big local-logo-img-big" src="#">Logo here
  </div>

</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <!--Start Sectors & Products-->
      <button class="dropdown-btn">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>button</span>
                    </button>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing you messed up was, you while opening you are adding `popoutwidth` class but when you close you were setting inline style as `width:0;`, this way when next time you were opening it, the code was working fine, but the inline style set by previous closing function causing the trouble.

```js
function openNav() {
  // event && event.stopPropagation();

  // document.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(mySidenav)[0], null).getPropertyValue("popoutwidth");
  // document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add('popoutwidth');
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "1";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.marginRight = "0";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove('popoutwidth');
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "28";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.marginRight = "15";

}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* margin-top: 18px; */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffffba;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.popoutwidth {
  width: 250px
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-11" style=" margin-top: 7px;">
    <span id="hamburger-icon" onclick="openNav()" style="vertical-align: middle; opacity: 1; font-size: 28px; margin-right: 15px;">☰</span>
    <img class=" logo-img-big local-logo-img-big" src="cms-images/logo.png">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <!--Start Sectors & Products-->
      <button class="dropdown-btn">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>button</span>
                    </button>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a class, set the width directly instead, like this:

```js
function openNav() {
  // event && event.stopPropagation();

  // document.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(mySidenav)[0], null).getPropertyValue("popoutwidth");
  // document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "1";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.marginRight = "0";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.fontSize = "28";
  document.getElementById("hamburger-icon").style.marginRight = "15";

}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* margin-top: 18px; */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffffba;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-11" style=" margin-top: 7px;">
    <span id="hamburger-icon" onclick="openNav()" style="vertical-align: middle; opacity: 1; font-size: 28px; margin-right: 15px;">☰</span>
    <img class=" logo-img-big local-logo-img-big" src="cms-images/logo.png">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

      <!--Start Sectors & Products-->
      <button class="dropdown-btn">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>button</span>
                    </button>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this dose, work however I need it to be classes as I have the css in media queries